# Ms Access change criteria of query using either a form or a report

Tags: ms-access

Hey I'm working on a database in access. Is there anyway in access I can be able to change the criteria for a query using either a report or a form so that the result set changes every time I change the criteria but the query remains the same e.g. 
SELECT customer FROM customers WHERE id = 2 this would be the query and the criteria is 2 I want to be able to change the id every time to get a different result set either via a report or a form or any other way other than the query itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to a form in a query:

```
 SELECT customer FROM customers WHERE id = Forms!MyForm!txtID
```

You can [open a report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192676.aspx) using a WHERE statement.